# Recording last logged in in grails with optimistic locking failure

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have had this code to record 'last logged in' for a while - since grails 1.3. Now at grails 2.2.4 and the 'optimistic locking failure' is annoying me. I think it only happens when I restart the application. I would like to know how to better go about it and avoid the 'optimistic locking errors'. There is spring-security and spring-security-ui involved.

```
class InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger('au.com.interlated.emissionscalculator.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEventListener')

    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

    ResPerson person
    try {
        ResPerson.withTransaction {
            person = ResPerson.findById(event.authentication.principal.id)
            if (!person.isDirty()) {
                if (!person.isAttached())
                    person.attach()


                person.lastLoggedIn = new Date()

                // doesn't save it is not the end of the world. Wondering if multiple requests at a time can cause this.
                try {
                    person.merge(flush: true)
```

Then I catch everything I can think of - both on the transaction and 'person.merge'. It isn't a huge problem if this update isn't made. In fact it probably got made because the filter got called by something else.

```
ERROR emissionscalculator.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEventListener  
- Object of class [au.com.interlated.springSecurity.ResPerson] with identifier [3100]: optimistic locking failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: 
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [au.com.interlated.springSecurity.ResPerson#3100]
```

I have tried catching a bunch of exceptions:

```
    } catch (e) {
        LOG.error "Failed to save login record : ${e.message}"
    } catch (OptimisticLockingFailureException olfe) {
        LOG.error "Failed to save login record. Optimistic Locking Failure."
    } catch (org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException sose) {
        LOG.error "Failed to save login record (stale object) ${sose.message}"
    }
```

Either avoiding the problem or at least catching it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lock` instead of `findById`. That way you have exclusive access for updates and can avoid optimistic lock issues. Also the `isDirty` and attached checks aren't needed, those are more for when you have a disconnected instance in the session (which in general is a bad idea) but you're loading the instance from the database. So this should work:

```
ResPerson.withTransaction {
   ResPerson person = ResPerson.lock(event.authentication.principal.id)
   person.lastLoggedIn = new Date()
   person.save()
}
```